# What happens when I block someone on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

As the title says, what happens when I block someone on LinkedIn?

What kind of information am I actually "blocking" them against?

Will my profile be visible? And if not, won't this be a clue for the other person that he has been blocked?

Will my posts and activity be visible or hidden? What should I do to only make my activity hidden from someone but leaving my profile visible (in order not to give clues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you block a member on LinkedIn, here's what will happen:

- You won't be able to access each other's profiles on LinkedIn
- You won't be able to message each other on LinkedIn
- You won't be able to see each other’s shared content.
- If you're connected, you won't be connected anymore
- LinkedIn will remove any endorsements and recommendations from that member
- You won't see each other under Who's Viewed Your Profile
- LinkedIn will stop suggesting you to each other in features such as People You May Know and People also Viewed

**Note:** LinkedIn won't notify the member that you blocked them, and only you’ll be able to unblock them.

**[https://www.linkedin.com/help/member-blocking](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/2839/member-blocking-overview?lang=en)**

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to only prevent someone to see my activity (so my posts, my replies to someone else posts, and so on)?

Comment: @Sekhemty unfortunately nope